# Notification created in Broadcast receiver disappears when the main activity is killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I am listening to the battery low system broadcast in my manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".BatteryLowReceiver"  android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then in my `.BatteryLowReceiver` I create a notification using `NotificationCompat.builder`

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    final PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Check for permissions
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Do stuff

                // Show notification
                showNotification(context, list.size());

                // Must call finish() so the BroadcastReceiver can be recycled.
                pendingResult.finish();
            } else {
                // TODO: failed because of permissions
                pendingResult.finish();
            }
            return "";
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();
}

void showNotification(Context context, int numberSent) {
    // Get pending intent
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set notification properties
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notif)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notif_title))
        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.notif_text))                           
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Display notification
    // TODO: Figure out why notif. goes away when the app is killed
    NotificationManager notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifyMgr.notify(NOTIF_ID, builder.build());
}
```

The notification shows up correctly when the low battery system broadcast is sent. However if I close my app's main activity, the notification does not persist. Is this the expected behavior? I would assume the notification stays until the user dismisses or clicks on it.

I believe it has something to do with context? I've tried removing the `AyncTask` part of the code but that does not help. I've made context a member variable to the class as suggested by another question. But no luck. How do I get the notification to stay until the user dismisses it?

Comment: setAutoCancel(false) should help you

Comment: @an_droid_dev autoCancel just makes it so the notifications clears when they click on it. Not when the activity is canceled. I tried it anyway and the notification is still disappearing. Thanks though.